Vector graphics interpreters like asy or gs
For the vector graphics languages Postscript and Asymptote there are the interactive command line interpreters gs and asy.
Directly seeing the result of the entered commands help me to stepwise develop a graphic/diagram.
Are there similar interpreters/previewers for Metapost, Graphviz, (g)pic, TikZ or similar languages for Unix/Linux?
Each of these languages excel in certain domains and are helpful in their own right, but I find it difficult to anticipate/imagine the output from the textual input.
I found one online TikZ previewer by Troy Henderson and one Metapost preview plugin for vscode, but would prefer command line programs/solutions. The closest solution I can imagine is opening the output file with gv/gs, which updates the view whenever I updated the output from vi or Emacs.

Build a dedicated Bash file should do the job.

For anything that you can build from within LaTeX (Metapost via luamp, TikZ) you can set up latexmk to run in continuous mode and auto-update your PDF viewer.

There is a learning curve, but you will get better at imagining the output when you keep creating figures - same as for example writing mathematics, or creating tables, or beamer slides. At first you need to compile at every step of the process and nothing fits nicely, but after some time you will be able to write (almost) the whole thing from scratch without compiling or preview and needing only minor corrections when you do compile it.

This is certainly true. In general, I think that computers and software should make the process of programming as accessible as possible for the users. Enabling quick feedback by preview functionality can be quite helpful in this regard.

Here is a Metapost answer.
Command line environment
You can use MP interactively from the command line, but it is not very useful -- it is more of a historical relic.  For example:
~> mpost
This is MetaPost, version 2.11 (TeX Live 2025/dev) (kpathsea version 6.4.0/dev)
**\relax
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/metapost/base/mpost.mp
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.005) )
*show sqrt 1/2;
>> 0.7071
*show down;
>> (0,-1)
*show unitsquare;
>> path (see the transcript file)
*end
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Transcript written on mpout.log.

In particular MP is missing any command to generate real-time graphical output.  In the ancestor program MetaFont there was a showit command that was used to generate a display of the current font character on an X-windows screen, but there is no such command in MP.  You do have the low-level shipit command, but that will just write the picture to a PostScript file (or PNG or SVG if you set the outputformat), and it only does it when you actually write shipit -- there is nothing to do real-time pictures as you type.
If you are more interested in just exploring the language you can follow the approach in Chapter 8 of Knuth's The Metafont Book.  Make a file called expr.mp with this content
string s[]; s1="abra";
path p[]; p1=(0,0)..(3,3); p2=(0,0)..(3,3)..cycle;
tracingonline:=1; scrollmode;
forever: message "gimme an expr: "; s0:=readstring;
show scantokens s0; endfor

and then run mpost expr from the command line.  For example
~> mpost expr.mp
This is MetaPost, version 2.11 (TeX Live 2025/dev) (kpathsea version 6.4.0/dev)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/metapost/base/mpost.mp
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.005) ) (./expr.mp
gimme an expr: sqrt 1/2
>> 0.7071
gimme an expr: abs -7
>> 7
gimme an expr: mexp 256
>> 2.71828
gimme an expr: ^C⏎ 

which is useful for exploring the language and understanding the way MP does arithmetic, but not for any interactive graphics.
Normal workflow
If you want to develop a drawing interactively then you need to use an editor and a previewer.  I know nothing about integrated development environments,
and I am aware that workflow is often a rather personal thing -- what works for Peter, may not work well for Paul.
But, for what it's worth, this is my workflow for single MP drawings.

I work on a Mac, and I use MacVim as my editor, and Skim.app to preview PDF files.
On Linux, the equivalents would be gvim as the editor, and one of the PDF viewers mentioned in the answers to this question from 2011.
When I am starting a drawing, I open the Terminal app, and navigate to the working directory I want to use, and then I open the editor with a new file name and an extension of .mp.  I have Vim set up so that it will write this template into the new file:
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
  <drawing goes here>
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}

As soon as I have something worth compiling, I run :!lualatex % from the Vim command line to produce a PDF file.   By default this will be written into the same working directory that I started in.
I then open the file with this from the Vim command line
:!open -a Skim %:r.pdf

The ! tells Vim to pass the command out to the shell, open -a Skim is Mac-speak for "open the following file with Skim.app" and the %:r.pdf is a bit of Vim magic that produces the current filename with the extension replaced with .pdf
With both windows open, I usually drag them so that they are tiled left and right on my screen (this is very easy with the new Sequoia window management features).
I then type away at my drawing, and run :!lualatex % to re-compile it.  And I have set up Skim.app to watch the PDF file for changes, and to reload it automatically (this is in Settings, on the Sync tab).
If you are good at Vim, you can set up a hook to automatically re-compile your drawing every time you save it, but that's too much automation for me.
Producing MP online
You might like to try Troy Henderson's online previewer.
